# How to localize array?

Tags: objective-c, localization, nsarray

I'm trying to translate my project to another languages, however I'm stuck when localizing my arrays. For example:

```
tableData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
    @"Test1",
    @"Test2",
    @"Test3",
    @"Test4",
    @"Test5",
    nil];
```

I've tried to

```
tableData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:NSLocalizedString
    (@"Test1",@"Test1"),
    (@"Test2",@"Test2"),
    ...
```

And

```
tableData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:NSLocalizedString
    ((@"Test1",@"Test1"),
    (@"Test2",@"Test2")),
    ...
```

But I get "Expression result unused."

All the procedure to generate an .strings file and localize everything else is good and working, I just need some help to find out how to write it down for an array.

Any tips?

Comment: Try: [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: NSLocalizedString(@"Test1",@"Test1"),NSLocalizedString(@"Test2",@"Test2")];

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shouldn't that be:

```
tableData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
    NSLocalizedString(@"Test1",@"Test1"),
    NSLocalizedString(@"Test2",@"Test2"),
    ...
    NSLocalizedString(@"TestN",@"TestN")
];
```

or (shorter):

```
tableData = @[
    NSLocalizedString(@"Test1",@"Test1"),
    NSLocalizedString(@"Test2",@"Test2"),
    ...
    NSLocalizedString(@"TestN",@"TestN")
];
```